# Can simplexml be used to rifle through html?

Tags: php, html, parsing, simplexml

I would like to grab data from a table without using regular expressions. I've enjoyed using simplexml for parsing RSS feeds and would like to know if it can be used to grab a table from another page.

Eg. Grab the page with curl or simply file_get_contents(); then use simplexml to grab  contents?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [`loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function from the DOM module, and then import that DOM into SimpleXML via [`simplexml_import_dom`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://example.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$sxml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
```

Comment: Big +1. Added a link to `simplexml_import_dom` and a tiny bit of further explanation.

Comment: Very nice trick. Unfortunately it looks like the DOM module isn't installed on the server I'm working on. Is it typically standard>?

Comment: @chris DOM and its dependency, libxml, are both compiled in by default. They can be explicitely left out in the compilation or disabled at runtime, but that's highly unusual.

Comment: Im getting Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in...' im assuming my school has a strange version of linux running on the server to have it missing. simplexml and libxml are available. I'll request they install it. Thx.

Answer (score 7):

If this is XHTML — yes, it's definitely possible. True XHTML is just XML in the end, so it can be parsed with an XML parser.

SimpleXML, however, only accepts strict XML. If you can't get valid XHTML it looks like putting it through the less-strict `DOMDocument` library first will do the trick ([source here](http://drewish.com/content/2007/08/using_simplexml_with_html)):

```
<?php
  $html = file_get_contents('http://...');
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

My version - tolerant to errors and problems with the encoding

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($this->html_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES',  'UTF-8'));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on a page. If page is in XHTML (most web pages nowadays) then any XML parser should do, otherwise look for SGML parser. Here's a similar question, you might be interested in: [Error Tolerant HTML/XML/SGML parsing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727/error-tolerant-html-xml-sgml-parsing-in-php)

Comment: MOST web pages? Source for that data pls? Also, please dig around SO (or internet in general) to find out why people usually don't serve XHTML correctly.