# Parsing HTML file in PhP

Tags: php, html, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error Tolerant HTML/XML/SGML parsing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727/error-tolerant-html-xml-sgml-parsing-in-php)

I am currently working on my new PHP project, in which i wish to parse the newsletters and then show its contents on my website. I was using **simple dom html parser** for this. But it does not work well as the news letters which i recieve are in very crude form. Many of the tags are not closed in news letters.

Can any of you help me out with some gus suggestions. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Look Forward.

Mahak

Comment: You can look at previously answer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727/error-tolerant-html-xml-sgml-parsing-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I consider phpquery library http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ to be one of the easiest way to achieve what you want especially if you are familiar with jQuery,