# extract image elements from html

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get the image tag out of html codes.

I have

```
   $parser=new DOMDocument;   

   $parser->loadHTML($this->html);
        foreach($parser->getElementsByTagName('img') as $imgNode){
         echo $parser->saveHTML($imgNode);
       }
```

`$this->html` contains massive html code and javascripts.

for example:

```
<div id='someid'>
<button id='bt' onclick='clickme()'>click me</button>
<img src='test.jpg'/>
.....
.....
more...

</div>

<div>
.....
.....
more...
```

I got an warning saying

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,
```

I am not sure how to fix this and don't know if there are a better way to extract all the images from the massive html codes.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in no way an expert on these matters (yet), but I hope this helps in some way.

According to [this answer by troelskn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613335/2005939) you can make the DOM parser more tolerant to badly formed HTML by using [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php). That might help you getting rid of that error.

Parsing all images of a document can be done by using [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). It takes a [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) as a parameter and lets you run [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) queries on the document.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($your_html);

// Suppress parse errors.
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($document)

// Find all img tags.
$img_nodes = $xpath->query('//img')
```

[`DOMXPath::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) which can be looped through using [`DOMNodeList::item`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php), which returns a [`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php).

```
for($i = 0; $i > $img_nodes->length; $i++)
{
    $node = $img_nodes->item($i);
    // Manipulate the node.
}
```

**Disclaimer:** The code I posted is untested and was put together using the manual.

Comment: "you can make the DOM parser more tolerant to badly formed HTML by using libxml_use_internal_errors"--wrong! This simply silences the errors. `loadHTML()` is already tolerant of html errors, although in a nonstandard way.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Upping the threshold of which something complains about a problem makes it more tolerant, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Saying "more tolerant" implies different parsing behavior, not different error reporting. Also the errors are still collected (by libxml), just not immediately sent to PHP's error-reporting layer, so arguably it's not "more tolerant" by your standard either.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Take [pain tolerance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_tolerance) for example. Even though a person wont shout out in pain, the pain might still be there, according to the [pain threshold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_threshold). So even if an individual experiences pain (read: the error is there), he might not feel the need to cry out (read: report an error) about it. Back to my answer, sure you could use that function to collect the errors later, but I'm using it to suppress them.